# Overlapping sticky elements but content keeps default scrolling

Tags: html, css, sticky

I'm somewhat struggling at wording my issue and didn't find a solution on the web yet.

My problem: I am creating full-viewport slides that should stack on top of each other (with transparency). There are plenty of solutions for this. But I want the content of the slides scroll normally, like you would expect to when you scroll a normal website (i. e. the text doesn't get stuck on top of the screen, but the background does).

Here is a plain-html example I'm playing around with for weeks. I don't know if this is the most promising solution, but I think it explains what I want to achieve. Note: the behaviour is already somewhat correct, but there is a lot of unnecessary spacing between the slides (= goal is to "connect" the grey background on the right without spacing). I assume there is a much better solution for this.

Updated this snippet to match a proposal from the comments. We apparently got closer, but there is a lot of unnecessary spacing as you can see in the updated snippet.

```css
body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        color: #000;
    }

    h1, h2, p {
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        position:relative;
    }
    h1 {
        margin-top: 40vh;
        min-height: 20vh;
        font-size: 48pt;
    }

    .background.a {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f00a, #fff0 10%);
    }
    .background.b {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fff3 20%, #0f0a 30%, #fffa 40%);
    }
    .background.c {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #fff3 50%, #00fa 60%, #fffa 70%);
    }

    .background {
        position: sticky;
        height: 100vh;
        top: 0;
    }

    .content {
        min-height: 100vh;
        position: relative;
        top: -100vh;
    }
```

```html
<div class="background a"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Some content</h1>
        <h2>creates slides with images ...</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="background b"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>More content</h1>
        <h2>creates slides with images ...</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="background c"></div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Some more content</h1>
        <h2>creates slides with images ...</h2>
    </div>
```

I hope you get what I want to achieve. I'm always wondering about these imprecise Stack Overflow questions, and now I don't do better in writing one myself ...
Thank you a lot. Please let me know if I should clarify something.

Comment: For additional help on how to write a good question checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: So you want the contents to scroll, but the backgrounds to stack one by one, maybe it's a better approach to think the backgrounds as another child elements, like this [example from css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/) with the description terms (`<dt>`).

Comment: @Leo yes, that does make sense, but I think I already tried something like this. The problem is, that the elements either push each other out of the view (like in the example, but they should stack), or I get a lot of unnecessary spacing I am unable to get rid off. I'll see if I can update my question with this try, maybe someone can help improve this. Thanks for the suggestion, let's see where this will lead.